# Searchkick - Autocomplete with multiple models & fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, autocomplete, typeahead.js, searchkick

Searchkick - Autocomplete with multiple models & fields

I am struggling to implement the [autocomplete functionality](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#instant-search--autocomplete) for multiple models associated to my `Post` model. The search functionality works fine and returns the expected data. My autocomplete method also works fine if I implement it the way it is done in the [documentation](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#heres-how-to-make-it-work-with-rails) (only for posts' title however).

I also tried [this answer](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/53#issuecomment-51884399) and this [one](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/53#issuecomment-51501600) by switching `Post.index.name` to `Post.searchkick_index.name` but the autocomplete functionality does not display.

This is the code I wrote in `posts_controller.rb`:

```
def autocomplete
    render json: Post.search(params[:query],
                             index_name: [
                               Post.searchkick_index.name,
                               Tag.searchkick_index.name,
                               User.searchkick_index.name
                              ],
                             limit: 10,
                             load: false,
                             misspellings: { below: 5 })
end
```

I also tried:

```
def autocomplete
  render json: Searchkick.search(params[:query],
                                 models: [Post, Tag, User],
                                 limit: 10,
                                 load: false,
                                 misspellings: { below: 5 })
end
```

I get no errors with the above code, but the autocomplete functionality does not work either.

In `post.rb`:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts_tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :posts_tags

  searchkick word_start: %i[title]

  def search_data
    {
      title: title,
      description: description,
      user: user.full_name
    }.merge(
      tag: tags.map(&:title),
      comments: comments.map(&:description)
    )
  end
end
```

As suggested in the answer section, I also tried the following:

```
def autocomplete
  posts = Post.search(params[:query], execute: false)
  tags = Tag.search(params[:query], execute: false)
  users = User.search(params[:query], execute: false)

  render json: Searchkick.multi_search([posts, tags, users])
end
```

This returns the following error: `fatal - exception reentered`.

I want to be able to autocomplete Post's **title**, Tag's **title** & User's **full_name**. How should I change my code?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From [multi_search](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#multi-search) of searchkick:

```
posts = Post.search(params[:query], execute: false)
tags = Tag.search(params[:query], execute: false)
users = User.search(params[:query], execute: false)

Searchkick.multi_search([posts, tags, users])
```

Comment: I get this error: `undefined method 'search' for #<Class:0x000000000c4db258>` for this line: `tags = Tag.search(params[:query], execute: false)`. Should I add `searchkick` in my Tag model?

Comment: Ok I added `searchkick` to both my Tag & User model but I get the following error now: `fatal - exception reentered:`.